# mongoTemplate use LookupOperation not find value

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I want to find articleReply value by _id of articleComment and commentId of articleReply.

_id of articleComment type is ObjectId, commentId of articleReply type is String.

I only find articleComment value and cannot find articleReply value.

find result eg:

```
{_id=60b312a73df6b758e09396d7, territoryId=1, articleId=60ac9e9a3df6b7312c4cbab0, userId=2, userAccount=163397@qq.com, userHeadImage=base/20210501234567.png, comment=帅哥, num=0, goodNum=0, activeFlag=1, updateTime=Sun May 30 12:20:55 CST 2021, createTime=Sun May 30 12:20:55 CST 2021, reply=[]}
```

my code:

```
public void readComment(String commentId){
    LookupOperation lookup1 = LookupOperation.newLookup()
            .from("articleReply")
            .localField("_id")
            .foreignField("commentId")
            .as("reply");
    MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is(commentId));
    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match,lookup1);
    AggregationResults<Map> articleComment = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,"articleComment",Map.class);
    System.out.println(articleComment.getUniqueMappedResult());}
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: First convert to string to ObjectId or ObjectId to string. Then dk the lookup

Comment: but i not find idea to convert type before lookup for the mongoTemplate

Answer (score 0):

I use db.runComment() execute mongodb origin sql get right data, yes i get right sql,then   springboot can use mongoTemplate.executeCommand(String sql) get right data.So it is resolved.
my mongo sql:

> {aggregate: "articleComment",
> pipeline: [
> { $match : {"_id" :ObjectId("60aca12d3df6b7312c4cbab1")}},
> {$project:{"aId": {"$convert": {"input": "$articleId","to": "objectId"}},"bId": {"$convert": {"input": "$_id","to": "string"}},
> "userId":1,"userAccount":1,"userHeadImage":1
> ,"comment":1,"num":1,"goodNum":1,"createTime":1} },
> {$lookup:{from: "article",localField: "aId",foreignField: "_id",as: "article" }},
> {$lookup:{from: "articleReply",localField: "bId",foreignField: "commentId",as: "articleReply" }}
> ],
> maxTimeMS: 10000,
> cursor: { }
> }